# How can I get git to stop asking for username and password?

Tags: git, github, ssh, zsh

I have successfully set up SSH per [GitHub Docs instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection).  I've also verified SSH works by using:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

However, after creating a new repository; I am prompted for a username / password which is deprecated.

How can I get Git to use the established SSH key pair?

My config file is as such which I verified is being used using `git config --list`:

```
[core]
  excludesfile = /Users/foo/.gitignore
    editor = subl -n -w
[remote "origin"]
  proxy = 
[user]
  name = foo
  email = not@my.email
[init]
  defaultBranch = main
[pull]
  rebase = false
```

Comment: Authentication is handled entirely by SSH or whatever connection protocol you are using; the Git configuration has nothing to do with it.

Comment: When, *exactly*, are you prompted for a username and password?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you're running git when it prompts for a password, including the github repository URL that you're trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using the HTTPS route for setting up a connection to the remote repositories since SSH is a bit tricky.

Here's what you need to do:

Setup Personal Access Token at `https://github.com/settings/tokens` and when prompted for a password enter your Personal Access Token.

Comment: The last part has nothing to do with authentication, either via SSH or using PATs.

Comment: Are tokens setup per repository or per my entire account?

Comment: Entire account if I recall correctly and  you have to options to customize for each possible permission

Comment: @chepner True. It is not a part of the authentication process but is associated with commit information and is required during setup.

Comment: OP isn't asking about any of that; there's no reason to expand your answer to include it.

Comment: @chepner I have edited the answer as per your suggestion. Thanks!